# android studio accessing properties of an object from different method

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner and this may be programming basics that I am missing here, but this is the only way I'll learn these things.

Below is my MainActivity code. It is trying to get details of the last location and read them into a class which I defined (class is called UserCurrentAddress) so that I can use those details.

I have declared the UserCurrentAddress class in the MainActivity class and then instantiated in the onCreate. I then use a button click (onClickView) at the bottom of the code to connect the API and get the location. The "handleNewLocation" method eventually populates the UserCurrentAddress object (and this works successfully). However when I try to read those details from the UserCurrentAddress in the buttonClick event (just using a Toast) it comes back as null. If I put that toast in the "handleNewLocation" then it is correctly populated. 
Why is it that the properties of the UserCurrentAddress are not visible from the buttonClick event?

I thought by declaring it in the Activity Class it would be visible throughout.

I realise I can probably do what I need to do within the "handleNewLocation" method, but it would be preferable to have access to those properties from outside that event.

I hope I've managed to explain my issue.

Code:

```
package com.example.android.trainingapp;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener{

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleAPIClient;
    private UserCurrentAddress userCurrentAddress;
    Button bFindLocation;
    private LocationRequest mlocationRequest;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bFindLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);
        bFindLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGoogleAPIClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mlocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);

        userCurrentAddress = new UserCurrentAddress(null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleAPIClient);

        if(location==null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleAPIClient, mlocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
        }
        else{
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }

    }

    public void handleNewLocation(Location location){

        double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
        String addressOne, addressTwo, streetNumber, country, fullAddress, postCode, myAdress;

        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {

            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, 1);

            if(addresses != null){
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
                }

                streetNumber = returnedAddress.getSubThoroughfare();
                addressOne = returnedAddress.getThoroughfare(); //Beech Rd
                addressTwo = returnedAddress.getLocality(); //durban north
                postCode = returnedAddress.getPostalCode();
                country = returnedAddress.getCountryName();
                myAdress = strReturnedAddress.toString();

                userCurrentAddress.streetNumber = streetNumber;
                userCurrentAddress.addressOne = addressOne;
                userCurrentAddress.addressTwo = addressTwo;
                userCurrentAddress.postCode = postCode;
                userCurrentAddress.country =country ;
                userCurrentAddress.latitude = currentLatitude;
                userCurrentAddress.longitude = currentLongitude;
                userCurrentAddress.fullAddress = myAdress;
                Toast.makeText(this, userCurrentAddress.streetNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{

                myAdress = "No Address Returned";

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            myAdress = "Cannot get address";
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.show_location:
                mGoogleAPIClient.connect();
                Toast.makeText(this, userCurrentAddress.fullAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access them? Another Activity, Fragment, Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing, this line:

```
       userCurrentAddress = new UserCurrentAddress(null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null);
```

must be getting executed *after* the `handleNewLocation()` call.

Try moving that line to a spot before the `GoogleApiClient.Builder` calls and see if that makes any difference.